# QML MouseArea hover stops working after changing the value when component clicked

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following code:

```
...
property var isEnabled: true;

Text {
    id: iconName
    color: isEnabled ?(mouseArea.containsMouse ? "blue": "white"): "black" 
    ...
}
MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    hoverEnabled: true
    onClicked:{
            if(isEnabled){
                isEnabled = false;
            }else{
                isEnabled = true;
            }
        mouse.accepted = false;
    }
    ...
```

When I launch the application, if I hover over iconName, the color changes from blue to white (depending on whether the mouse is over the text or not).

If I click, iconName turns blue, but I was expecting to see it changes to black.

Am I missing something? Any tip?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked, whether all your places talk about the same `isEnabled` or whether there might be another one in the name resolution chain that might be taken from the one, but not from the other, or whether `isEnabled` is found at all (as you don't specify it with an id, it might not be in the root node)

Comment: And you should use `bool` instead of `var` for `isEnabled`

Comment: easier to read would be `onClicked: [id].isEnabled = ![id].isEnabled` to toggle a bool. If not in the same object, it is good practice to always use the [id].[propertyName]-syntax, as for minor modifications, the property might leave the scope of name resolution.

Comment: i just ran your code, it works fine for me. Windows 7, Qt 5.7.0. What size is the parent item, to which mouseArea is anchored? Maybe the parent item is too small and the mouseArea is not clickable

Comment: it's a rectangle (340px 440px). The mousearea matches with the previous rectangle area. It seems as it is assigning the property only on the function, but it loses the ability to continuisly checking if mouse.contains after onPressed is called once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MouseArea component might be an unexpected size. Color the MouseArea component to make sure that you are clicking in the right place, for example:

```
Item {
    id: topItem

    property var isEnabled: true;

    width: 50
    height:50

    Text {
        id: iconName
        color: topItem.isEnabled ?(mouseArea.containsMouse ? "blue": "white"): "black"
        text: "hello world!"
        font.pointSize: 20
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked:{
                if(topItem.isEnabled){
                    topItem.isEnabled = false;
                }else{
                    topItem.isEnabled = true;
                }
            mouse.accepted = false;
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: mouseArea
            color: "red"
            opacity: 0.2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the area matches with the one expected.